# Redirect back to screen after user logins on android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

In my app I have a Login button on the action bar, after user clicks the Login button they will be redirected to a new activity called LoginActiviy, after user logins successfully, I would like to redirect them back to the original screen, and that could be an activity or a fragment under an activity. Any idea how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Do Like this,

first currentActivity - LoginActivity

```
Intent loginIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(loginIntent);
```

//After login success on LoginActivity

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
LoginActivity.finish();
```

it again back to onActivityResult of CurrentAcitivity

Then from onActivityResult, you can go to any desired activity